# Have grub boot into certain OS if button is held

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I would like to be able to boot into a certain OS in the Grub menu if a button is held.

Comment: Don't think grub does that. You'd need to modify its source code, build it, potentially sign it (if you're doing secure boot) and install it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure if that's want you need, but here's a GRUB entry to boot Windows when the <kbd>W</kbd> key is pressed (not "held").

```
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-AAAA-BBBB' --hotkey='w' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AAAA-BBBB
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Also I have <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> for power off and reboot respectively:

```
menuentry 'Poweroff  [p]' --hotkey='p' {
    halt
}

menuentry 'Reboot  [r]' --hotkey='r' {
    reboot
}
```

Comment: This means that when you are at the grub menu, you can just press `W` instead of navigating to the Windows entry with the down keys, right? I think you're right in saying it's not what the OP needs, but it's still cool! I didn't know grub had that option.

Comment: *you can just press W instead of navigating to the Windows entry with the down keys* - yes. I'm a very lazy person, so I enabled it as soon as I learned about its existence. :-)

Comment: Actually this is pretty much what i was looking for, because of my setup i cant see grub so i have trouble booting into my other os

Comment: @Hugodijkstra happy to hear it helps! I edited your comment slightly for language; please keep it professional on the U&L site. Thank you!